# WebClient.DownloadString not working on deployment (The Operation has timed out)

Tags: c#, https, webclient, recaptcha

I have this method

```
public bool IsValidCaptcha(string gtoken)
{
    WebClient webclient = new WebClient();

    string json = webclient.DownloadString("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=1234567890&response=" + gtoken);
    JToken jtoken = jtoken.Parse(json);

    return Convert.ToBoolean(jtoken("success"));
}
```

It's working fine on my localhost but not after I publish it to the server. It gave me `System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out`. I already make sure the server have internet connection because I can use browser and hit the URL just fine.

Any idea why?